# select ALL pdf in Books on iPad to upload to Mac

Tags: ipad, catalina

Is there a way to select ALL pdf in Books on iPad to upload via AirDrop to a Mac?

In fact I would welcome suggestions for ANY means of bulk transfer.

Comment: Do you want to bulk move only the commercial eBooks? Or do you want to move any pdf, even those that are generated from Safari page prints and other internal printouts - that is, on a website opened in Safari, you can choose the "send to"- button and then the orange symbol for books, do you want to include them as well?

Comment: In case you want to bulk move ALL pdfs (including Safari page prints), there is no solution without a 3rd party app at the moment. At least there is a solution at all, having invested many days to find out about it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434692/iphone-move-in-one-go-all-pdfs-generated-from-safari-page-prints-which-i-fr. In so far, this question would be a cross-post duplicate of the Stack Overlow question there.

Comment: @Lorenz Your first comment is confusing, and seems to be the opposite of what I was asking. The second comment "Decipher Backup Browser" seems like an option (although the link is very confusing). I downloaded the app to my iMac, and it seems to find files, but I do not need to do for my own. I will try on my wife's iPad/MacBook. She has/had hundreds of pdf downloaded (some paid with a limited download period) which Apple seems to automatically delete on sync.

Comment: An explicit Answer would be welcome and may help others. My wife will ultimately decide if her backup has the files and if it is worth the purchase price for a one off recovery.

Comment: My comment might not be clear because it was not trying to answer, it was a question to your question. I am not about to answer here before I do not know whether this is a duplicate. If you want to also bulk move pdf printouts from Safari websites, this is simply a duplicate of that SO question. If instead you simply want to bulk move the commercial e-books or at least downloads of type "e-book", the answer would be to follow "Unsuccessful try only using iBooks and iTunes" in the given link's answer, and then it should be clear in your question that you only need e-books and no other PDFs.

Comment: By the way, I do not belong to that company and I do not get any provisions, I simply think that it was so utterly helpful to me that I have the courage of promoting it. And up to now, I do not see any alternative, having invested so much time with the full rest of the community just sending mails piece by piece or uploading to the cloud piece by piece (of pdf printouts) without any helpful support for my bulk move question. I am still baffled that I had to find out about this "on my own", no one could help out or was even interested. I also had a bounty on this, no answer.

Comment: Again, in your case, iTunes might suffice, as I said before, the purchased 3rd party app is only needed if you need ALL pdfs, including those that are no e-books.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I asked about pdf, not eBooks nor Safari page prints. Most of the pdf came from an iPad2 and are of unknown provenance. I would love to use iTunes, but sadly that no longer exists on Catalina.

Comment: Your mentioned Catalina was not known to me, I have simply ignored it, though it is the essential part of your question and most probably takes away the risk of being a duplicate of the other question. There is a new and separate Apple Books app on Catalina, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210200. Perhaps Apple has even finally also taken care of the issue of pdf web page prints I was struggling with? Have you already tried Apple Books on Catalina to transfer the pdfs? Then, the iTunes (+ optional 3rd party app) solution is only needed on Windows, which you do not use.

Comment: If the pdfs have been added from pc to the Apple device, my experience is that they also were shown in iTunes anyway. I cannot say how this is with pdfs that have been downloaded. What I know for sure is that the web page printouts were not shown. I hope that in the new Apple Books app on Catalina you will see all of your pdfs, whatever their source, since we can expect that a new program is better. If not, and if you do not find a workaround in Apple Books, your very last workaround is to take a Windows PC and follow the answer of the Stack Overflow question.